# Kafka HTTP Topic Producer configuration acks=all

Tags: http, apache-kafka, producer

How do we set acks=all for KAFKA HTTP Topic? I tried sending in the below JSON as "acks":"all" But it throws with an unrecognized property. I tried setting it in the header as well. But in Header when I set to any value like 0,1, all and abcd. It is accepting all the values. So I can't rely on the header. But from Java code, we can set this property as ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG as key-value pair

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "value": { "name": "Firstname, lastname" },
            "key":"123e4567-e89b-42d3-a456-5566424415123591"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any Suggestions are helpful.

Comment: what do you mean bu Kafka Http?

Comment: I mean Kafka Rest

Comment: [https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/issues/195](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/issues/195) look this, it will help

Comment: Can you explain how you do config `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` to rest kafka producer?

Answer (score 1):

In case of Kafka REST Proxy, the producer instances are shared between clients i.e. the client(s) will connect to REST proxy instance(s) and those REST proxy instance(s) will in turn connect to the Kafka cluster (brokers).

The `json` that you have supplied is only going to contain data records.

The REST proxy layer will have the global settings for producers that you're looking for and clients will end up sharing these. So, if you've got access to the REST proxy instances then you could modify these parameters there directly.